What do we do with the truth about the Sabbath and Sunday?
Knowing that the pagans changed Christ’s words on the cross from "Father, why have you forsaken me" to what Christ actually said, "This is for the Sabbath keepers" then working out our own Salvation with fear and trembling makes things complicated when worshipping with other Believers on Sunday.
God knows our hearts, but this truth brings certain conflicts both in my mind and heart! What's others convictions about this as times grow darker?

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Renee. Unfortunately, this question is not appropriate for this cite as it does not provide a verse needed to apply hermeneutics to. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. Also consider going through the Help Center.
